# Can I use a colon in the following sentence?

Tags: punctuation

> According to information from the news agency Reuters: safety experts warned the Lebanese government back in July of the devastating effects the explosion would cause.

Does the word after the colon need to be capitalized?

Comment: That is not a typical way to use a colon.  We would normally just use a comma there.  Is there a particular reason why you want to use a colon?

Comment: In AmE, the word after the colon is usually capitalised; in BrE, usually not.

Answer (score 1):

You would not normally use a colon.  A comma is sufficient here.

A colon can be used before a list or an example. It has the meaning "... and they are..." or "...namely..."

> There are three gems that are considered most valuable: ruby, sapphire and diamond.

> There is one gem that everybody wants: diamond.

Nobody capitalises the first letter in this case (unless it is a proper noun)

You can also use it to join two clauses where the second clause explains or gives an example of the first.

> Talking is not enough: you have to take action!

Americans would often capitalize; Britons would usually not capitalize. However in both dialects there is individual variation.

In your example there is just an introductory phrase, not two linked clauses.  This should be separated with a comma.

> According to information from the news agency Reuters, safety experts warned the Lebanese government back in July of the devastating effects the explosion would cause.